# css hover relative elements using ~ or > sign

Tags: css

```
<section class="services-section" id="services">
<video src="services.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
<div class="container section-padding services-d-content">
  <h3 class="left-liner">Services</h3>
  <p>List of my services</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="service-content">
        <h3 class="bottom-liner">Here is my services</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul>
              <li>sliders</li>
              <li>max 10 section per page</li>
              <li>carousels</li>
              <li>image gallery</li>
              <li>awesome background particles!</li>
              <li>Countdown (Realtime server side)</li>
              <li>contact form</li>
              <li>Pixel Perfect Design</li>
              <li>All code is hand coded</li>
              <li>W3C Validated</li>
              <li>Quickly Converted PSD to Html</li>
              <li>Highly Professional code!</li>
              <li>Cross-Browser Compatibility</li>
              <li>jQuery effects</li>
              <li>animated content in On scroll</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul>
              <li>Highly Professional Design</li>
              <li>100% Unlimited revisions</li>
              <li>Mobile-Friendly websites</li>
              <li>E-commerce with various payment methods</li>
              <li>Websites for All professions</li>
              <li>Secure Websites</li>
              <li>Custom Designing(if you say)</li>
              <li>User-friendly and attractive layout</li>
              <li>Opt in form (MY SQL DATABSE)</li>
              <li>Meta description</li>
              <li>maps</li>
              <li>Free 3Month support</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
      <img src="img/services.png" class="img-fluid Services-scale-up" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </section>





  **css 
   #services:hover > .Services-scale-up{
     transform: scale(1.1);
   }**
```

- Heading ##i want to scale up the image when #services hover i have
  used ~ this sign Also! can anyone tell me how to scale up a image
  when i hover the parent section i have tried both ~ and > sign i dont
  know more sign to hover parent element

========================================================================

Comment: Hi. What's the question? :) Plz visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [what](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: i want to scale up the targeted img inside a section When the section hover over

Comment: look my code line number 1 (section) 
want to hover the 50th line number image